# :Find the parameter m so the equation has real solution

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

Recently, I have found this problem:

> Find the parameter $m \in \Bbb{R}$ so the equation has real solution 
>   $$\cos^2(2x)+3m^2=4m(\cos^4(x)-\sin^4(x))$$

I suppose that the answer is $\forall m \in \Bbb{R}$, but how can we show this?

I have tried to factor the right side, obtaining $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)$, but how can we go on?

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem? How far did you get?

Comment: Why are you interested in this question and how did you try to solve it?

Comment: If you say _the_ parameter, how do you know there is only one such parameter?

Comment: cos^2(2x)-4mcos(2x)+3m^2=0

Comment: $\cos^4(x) - \sin^4(x) = \cos(2x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to factor the right side:
$$\cos^2(2x)+3m^2=4m(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x))(\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x))\leftrightarrow \cos^2(2x)+3m^2=4m\cos(2x)$$
Let $t=\cos(2x)$, we have:
$$t^2-4mt+3m^2=0$$
Using the quadratic formula, we arrive at:
$$t=\frac{4m\pm\sqrt{16m^2-12m^2}}{2}=\frac{4m\pm2m}{2}=3m \; \vee \; m$$
Now, you have to study $\cos(2x)=m$ and $\cos(2x)=3m$ that have real solutions if $m \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: How does this assure that $x$ is real?

Comment: @sampleuser: sorry, my error. See my edits.

Comment: why it has real solution only on [ -1,1]?

Comment: @Mike: because if $m$ is not in $[-1,1]$ there are no solution $x$  in $\cos(2x)=m$ and $\cos(2x)=3m$

Comment: how can I prove it?

Comment: @Mike it seems you are just ignoring a lot of questions asked to you. For example on your question and the problems you have with my answer. This is not how MSE works.

Comment: ok, sorry for it

Comment: @Mike: if it has been useful maybe a $+1$?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution always is $$x=\frac{1}{2}\cos^{-1}(m)\in \mathbb R$$ for $|m|\leq 1$.

To see that this is a solution, just plug in $x$ into the equation and use that $\cos^4(x)-\sin^4(x)=\cos(2x)$: $$\cos^2(\cos^{-1}(m))+3m^2=4m\cos(\cos^{-1}(m))),$$ that is, $$m^2+3m^2=4m^2$$ which holds for all $m$.

Comment: I need values of m, not x

Comment: As I wrote, for every value of $m$ there is real solution. In other words, all values of $m$ are fine.

Comment: the solution should be (-1,1).. and i do not understand why

Comment: What precisely do you not understand? I don't see where in your question you want the solution to be in the interval $(-1,1)$. However, as I demonstrated in the answer, for every value of $m$ your equation has a real solution which is precisely what you were asking for. Please clarify what causes confusion or with which part of the answer you are not satisfied.

Comment: I think sampleuser is making some kind of point here. Indeed we are not interested in the value of $x$, but rather $m$. But sampleuser has given us an expression. When does the expression return real values? Certainly $m=1000$ doesn't give a real answer. How about $|m|\leq 1$ ?

Comment: @MattiP. Well, the question was for which values of $m$ there exists a real solution $x=x(m)$ to the equation and this is precisely what I provided. You are of course correct in saying that for $|m|>1$ there are some issues. I'll edit my answer, thanks! :)